# pip install of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, pycharm

I have recently attempted to install pandas through pip. It appears to go through the process of installing pandas and all dependencies properly. After I update to the latest version through cmd as well and everything appears to work; typing in pip show pandas gives back information as expected with the pandas version showing as 1.5.3

However, it appears that when attempting to import pandas to a project in PyCharm (I am wondering if this is where the issue lies) it gives an error stating that it can't be found. I looked through the folders to make sure the paths were correct and that pip didn't install pandas anywhere odd; it did not.

I uninstalled python and installed the latest version; before proceeding I would like to know if there is any reason this issue has presented itself. I looked into installing Anaconda instead but that is only compatible with python version 3.9 or 3.1 where as I am using the newest version, 3.11.2

Comment: Did you use anaconda for PyCharm? If so you need to activate the environment before installing pandas

Comment: If you are working in any virtual environment, you should install `Pandas` in that env.

Comment: I did not use anaconda for PyCharm; it has not been installed onto my system as of yet. I have no virtual environments and only use the PyCharm IDE for any python code.

Comment: Are you having problems with any other packages?

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me

1. I reload the environment variables by running the command

   source ~/.bashrc

   right in the pycharm terminal.
2. I make sure the I have activated the correct venv (where the package installations go) by cd to path_with_venv then running

   source ~/pathtovenv/venv/bin/activate
3. If that does not work, hit CMD+, to open your project settings and and under Python Interpreter select the one with the venv that you have activated. Also check if pandas appears on the list of packages that appear below the selected interpreter, if not you may search for it and install it using this way and not the pip install way

Comment: Do you believe this will work if there are no virtual environments available in PyCharm. To clarify, I know PyCharm has the ability to create venv, I just haven't set any up.

Comment: @Nathan What happens when you try installing pandas through PyCharm's "Python Packages" tab? If it allows you to install, and everything works, then find out where the package was installed.

Comment: @Misplaced Southerner I have not yet tried installing it that way. Sort of slipped my mind somehow. To answer your other question; pandas is the only one giving me issues. I'll try installing through PyCharm's "Python Packages" and see if that works.